# Specify compiler for python to use

Tags: python, python-2.7, compiler-construction, pip

When using pip or installing other modules from source files python always try to execute gcc. I have a gcc installed with cygwin but that is massively outdated version. Can I tell python to use VC compiler instead? my os is windows 8.1

Comment: Have you tried using `-p file/path`? That's how you do it for `virtualenv`.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean? do you mean python -p or pip -p? @IanAuld

Comment: Are you running Cygwin Python or the Windows-installed Python?

Comment: windows-installed @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams